# Problem with my array while making monopoly game

Tags: c#, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create an array to store all the positions that are available on a monopoly board but when creating the array I get the error that

> "Cannot implicitly convert type '(string,string,string,string,string)'
> to string"

.

```
 private void pictureBox1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[,,,,]BoardPos;
            BoardPos = new string[39, 0, 4, 0, 0];
            BoardPos[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] = ("Go", "+200", "CurrentPlayer", "", "");
            BoardPos[1, 0, 0, 0, 0] = ("Old Kent Road", "-60", "CurrentPlayer", "", "");
        }
```

Comment: `("Go", "+200", "CurrentPlayer", "", "")` is a value tuple of four strings. `BoardPos[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` is a single string in the multi-dimensional array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This syntax:

```
("Go", "+200", "CurrentPlayer", "", "");
```

is actually creating a tuple of strings, rather than a string array.

The fix is to rewrite your code to take advantage of C#'s object-oriented nature. I would recommend you simplify your code by creating a class to hold the relevant fields:

```
public interface IMonopolySquare
{
     public string Name { get; }
     public void PlayerLandsOnEvent(Player player);
     public void PlayerPassesSquareEvent(Player player);
     public void SetOwner(Player player);
}

public class GoSquare : IMonopolySquare
{
     public string Name { get => "Go" }

     public void PlayerLandsOnEvent(Player player)
     {
          // Do nothing - player has to pass to receive £200.
     }

     public void PlayerPassesSquareEvent(Player player)
     {
         player.AddMoney(200);
     }

    public void SetOwner(Player player)
    {
        throw new Exception ("You can't buy go!!");
    }
}

public class PropertySquare : IMonopolySquare
{
    private Player _owner = null;
    private int _rentWithoutHouse;
    private Color _color;

    public PropertySquare(
        string name,
        int rentWithoutHouse,
        Color color)
    {
        Name = name;
        _rentWithoutHouse = rentWithoutHouse;
        _color = color;
    }

    public string Name {get;}
     public void PlayerLandsOnEvent(Player player)
     {
         if (_owner != null && _owner != player)
         {
             player.SubtractMoney(_rentWithoutHouse); 
         }
     }

     public void PlayerPassesSquareEvent(Player player)
     {
         // Do nothing.
     }

    public void SetOwner(Player player)
    {
        if (owner != null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Can't buy something that's already been bought!");
        }
        else
        {
            _owner = player;
        }
    }
}

// the Player class is left as an exercise for the reader...
```

And then your "board" becomes the much simpler:

```
var board = new IMonopolySquare[] {
    new GoSquare(),
    new PropertySquare("Old Kent Road", "2", Color.Brown),
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `GoSquare` implement `IMonopolySquare`?

Comment: Brilliant that's great! Thank you very much